# Let $B$ be symmetric and positive definite. Show that the range of $B - \frac{Bss^TB}{s^TB} $ is $n-1$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, optimization

Let $B\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ simetric and positive definite and $s\in\mathbb{R}^n-\{0\}$.

Let $M := B - \frac{Bss^TB}{s^TBs}$.Show that the range of the matrix $M$ is $n-1$ and find its null space.

My try:
Let's find the null space. Let $x\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Then $Mx=Bx - \dfrac{Bss^TBx}{s^TBs}=_{set}$, so $Bx=\dfrac{Bss^TBx}{s^TBs}$.

Since $B$ is invertible, I know that for a linear independent set of vectors $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_k\}\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. ${Bv_1,Bv_2,...,Bv_k} is linearly independent.

Then the range of $B$ must be $n-1$.

I'm not sure if the null space is the vector $\frac{Bss^TBx}{s^TBs}$.

Comment: note the *range* is a set whereas the *rank* is conjectured to be $n-1$ here.  You've shown $M\succeq \mathbf 0$ in a prior post so for null space it suffices to find $\mathbf x$ such that $\mathbf x^T M\mathbf x =0$.  btw the fact that $\text{rank}(A+B)\leq \text{rank}(A)+\text{rank}(B) \implies \text{rank}(M) \geq n-1$.

Answer (score 1):

A fact:$$Ms=Bs-\frac{Bss^tBs}{s^tBs}=Bs-Bs=0.$$

And $\mathrm{rank}(M)\geq \mathrm{rank}(B)-\mathrm{rank}(\frac{Bss^tB}{s^tBs})=n-1.$